# i have custom object, i want connect product object to my custom object, same to opportunity, how it possible?

Tags: apex

> In custom object i created  a look-up field for product object, how i
>   can utilize the add product button in standard way.

Answer (score -1):

If you created look-up field you can add the field do page layout - you will be able to connect your desired objects in this way (while doing standard editing i.e. by using tab, not custom vf pages)